# Express route isn't executed when JSON file is requested

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I defined a route in my Express app that supposed to execute a line of code then return a JSON file, but what happens is that the file is returned, but the line of code isn't executed.

This is the server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var body_parser = require("body-parser");
var path = require('path');

server = express();
server.use(body_parser.json());
server.use(body_parser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

server.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("index.html");
});

server.get("/request.json", function(req, res) {
    console.log('File \"request.json\" requested.')
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/request.json")
});

server.listen(80, function() {
    console.log("Server listening on port 80");
});
```

Inside `index.html` there is only a script tag defined like:

```
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){       
            $.getJSON("/request.json", function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

I can see the content of `request.json` file in chrome console, but the expected message `"File "request.json" requested"` isn't displayed on server's terminal.

Why the route isn't being executed?

Comment: Because you have a static `use()`, `server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));` before your `get()` routes. That is consuming the request and not passing it on since there is a physical file at that location

Comment: Thanks a lot! Aftet your response i took a look at express.static docs and everything makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The `express.static` is called before the `/request.json` route and already returns the file.
Use this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require('path');

server = express();
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

server.get("/request.json", function(req, res) {
    console.log('File \"request.json\" requested.')
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/request.json")
});

server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

server.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("index.html");
});

server.listen(80, function() {
    console.log("Server listening on port 80");
});
```

Comment: bad practice to move static below

Comment: @ xdeepakv It must be below the ``/request.json``

Comment: check my answer, if u see what i mean

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom `static middleware`. Can write logic to not to serve file`[exclude]`.

**Note:** Note recommend from me, better change route name of `/response.json`

```
var express = require("express");

var path = require("path");
var app = express();
var statics = express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/"));
function customServe(secure) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.path);
    if (req.path != "/response.json") return statics(req, res, next);
    return next();
  };
}
app.use(customServe());
app.get("/response.json", (req, res) => {
  console.log("something...");
  res.send({ json: "json" });
});
app.listen(8080, () => console.log("working on 8080"));
```